# Different version of AngularJS in pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing new features of application which is using AngularJS v1.2.x and Bootstrap v2.3.x. I want to apply new version of AngularJS (v1.4.6) and Bootstrap v3.3.x in one/some pages of application without affecting to old versions.

Thank you for helps.

Found some info but it's not help :(
[Multiple versions of AngularJS in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537960/multiple-versions-of-angularjs-in-one-page)

Comment: I don't think you should be trying to do this. Migrate to the new version or stay in the old one, but don't try to run two versions at the same time. (not possible with Bootstrap, hairy and difficult with Angular)

Comment: Thank David Boskovic for advise. However, I am implementing a new feature which uses open source angular-bootstrap-calendar. It is required newest version of AngularJS and Bootstrap. That why I need to apply new version of AngularJS and Bootstrap in one/some pages without changing application's source code.

Comment: Why not update all of your modules to use the latest version? The compatibility issues should be minor.

Comment: We can not upgrade because the new version affect to existing features and GUI of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by thinking those pages as Components. you could so add an angular version for each module . Plus if a module is down he will not affect the others.

In your main app.js you will have to add those modules