# How to isolate javascript dependencies

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to isolate parts of a page, so that each part can use a different javascript framework (or version).

For eample

```
<div id="content1">
    Uses angular 1.5/jquery 1.x/etc
</div>
<div id="content2">
    Uses angular 2/jquery 2.x/etc 
</div>
<div id="content3">
    Uses react/jquery 2/etc
</div>
```

Is it possible to isolate each snippet such that they don't interfere with each other regardless of what framework they use?

Obviously i could use iframes, but is there another solution?

Comment: It's possible with sandboxing techniques, yes, but there's hardly a good reason to do this.

Comment: What sandboxing techniques exist?  I know you can do it with iframes.  What others exist?

Comment: Apart from the `noconflict` methods of the libs themselves, have a look at Google Caja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The JS environment is "the window/frame", you can't narrow it further than that.

Answer (score 1):

its somehow feasible but its hard to maintain and you have to handle that yourself, not HTML will choose the lib version according to which element,

for example:

- jQuery: you can use [jQuery noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to load multiple jQuery version in same page,
- Angular: check this answer for [Multiple versions of AngularJS in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537960/multiple-versions-of-angularjs-in-one-page)
- React: its different framework than angular so both can work side by side and you can handle which framework to work with each part in the page.