# Angularjs multiple applications possibility

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an angularjs application using angular 1.3 with ui state routing, etc. Now I need to work on dashboards for this project. But I have came across https://github.com/getredash/redash which is providing all my needed dashboard features, charts, tables, etc. I have noticed that the client code of it is done with Angularjs 1.5. They have used component architecture and ng-routing. Now, in my original application, I want to include new tab and link that tab to this redash client application, is it possible? I mean in my existing angularjs 1.3 application, I want to put another angularjs 1.5 application in a separate tab. Is it possible, if yes, can any one suggest me the guidelines to proceed on this further.

Comment: By 'new tab' you mean new browser window? Because having two apps on the same page is a bad idea, unless you know what you're doing very well. And having two Angular versions doesn't make this any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different versions of angular 1. Here are some links you can look into:

[Multiple versions of AngularJS in one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537960/multiple-versions-of-angularjs-in-one-page)

http://www.mattburkedev.com/multiple-angular-versions-on-the-same-page/